# Actionscript 3.0 character also shoots when I move

Tags: flash, actionscript

I had to make this simple game for school, but as a designer, I'm not very good at this sort of stuff.

The problem is that when the event that I made that shoots bullets when I press the spacebar also shoots bullets when I move up or down, which I don't want it to do.  I know it's probably some silly mistake, but please help me out.  My game is a side scroller kind of game like space shooter.

Also I wanted to ad a shooting animation when he shoots the bullets but it wont show, the shooting animation I added with `gotoAndstop(4);`

Here is all of my code:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.sensors.Accelerometer;
import flash.events.Event;

var links:Boolean = false;
var rechts:Boolean = false;
var snelheid:int = 0;
var enemyy:MovieClip;



var enemies:MovieClip=new MovieClip();
stage.addChild(enemies);
for (var teller:int=1; teller<=20; teller++)
{
    enemyy=new Blueenemy();
    enemies.addChild(enemyy);
    enemyy.x = 250 + 170 * teller + Math.round(Math.random() * 30);
    enemyy.y = 50+ Math.round(300*Math.random());
}
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,altijd);
function altijd(evt:Event)
{
    enemies.x -=  10;
}






stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,toets);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,toets);
main_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,lopen);
function toets(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE);
    {

        var bullet:Bullet=new Bullet();
        bullet.x = main_mc.x + 37;
        bullet.y = main_mc.y + -10;
        stage.addChild(bullet);
        bullet.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,beweeg);
        function beweeg(evt:Event)
        {
            bullet.x +=  15;

        }
    };
    if (evt.keyCode == 38)
    {

        if (evt.type == "keyDown")
        {
            links = true;
            main_mc.gotoAndStop(3);
            snelheid = -15;
        }
        else
        {
            links = false;
        }
    }
    if (evt.keyCode == 40)
    {
        if (evt.type == "keyDown")
        {
            rechts = true;
            main_mc.gotoAndStop(2);
            snelheid = 15;
        }
        else
        {
            rechts = false;
        }
    }
}
function lopen(evt:Event):void
{
    main_mc.y +=  snelheid;
    if (! links && ! rechts)
    {
        main_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
        snelheid = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could see, short of trying to execute your code on my machine, is the fact that you have not specified an if statement properly here along with a few other little things that could be improved:

```
function toets(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE);
    {

        var bullet:Bullet=new Bullet();
        bullet.x = main_mc.x + 37;
        bullet.y = main_mc.y + -10;
        stage.addChild(bullet);
        bullet.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,beweeg);
        function beweeg(evt:Event)
        {
            bullet.x +=  15;

        }
    };

    // ... rest of code in your function
}
```

This should be:

```
function toets(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE)
    {

        var bullet:Bullet=new Bullet();
        bullet.x = main_mc.x + 37;
        bullet.y = main_mc.y + -10;
        stage.addChild(bullet);

        var beweeg:Function = function(evt:Event)
        {
            bullet.x +=  15;
        };

        bullet.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,beweeg);

    }

    // ... rest of code in your function
}
```

Notice:

1. I removed the `;` at the end of the `if` condition
2. Improved the `beweeg` function declaration within your function
3. reordered the `beweeg` function declaration so it is before it is used
4. removed `;` at the end of the first `if` block